# Как сделать квадратное поле в консоли?

Tags: java

Мне нужно, чтобы в консоли вывелось квадратное поле из #, например, размером 5x5
Но у меня это не совсем выходит:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            System.out.println("#");
```

Задумывалось так, что под каждым i будет выстраиваться столбик и в итоге должно получиться поле, но все идет в один столбик. Прошу помощи у более опытных.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    System.out.print("#");
  System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Мда, мне стыдно стало. Но огромное спасибо)